# index out of bounds in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am not able to get how to run it, can anyone help me on this please.

I am receiving this error :

```
 K>> [minutiae_valid]=postprocess_TICO(B,im,~K)
??? Attempted to access wind(273,386); index out of bounds because size(wind)=[368,385].

Error in ==> postprocess_TICO at 214
if (thinned(p,q)==1)&&(wind(p,q)==0)
```

postprocess_Tico

```
function [minutiae_valid]=postprocess_TICO(minutiae_valid,im1,thinned)
% clc;
% close all; 
% clear all;
cell=16;%total no. of cells needed in quantization;
% im1= imread('E:\FINGERPRINT DATABASE\FVC2002\Dbs\Db1_a\16_6.tif');
wl=(33-1)/2; 
% no=20;
% no2=20;
% nox = 0;
% noy = 0;  %to choose border area
% 
m=size(im1,1);
n=size(im1,2);
%m=(round(m/cell))*cell;
%n=(round(n/cell))*cell;
% im1=imresize(im1,[m n]);
% im=double(im1);
% figure;
% subplot(1,2,1);
% imshow(uint8(im));
% title('original input image');
% 
% %Identify ridge-like regions and normalise image--------------------------
%  blksze = 10;   
%  thresh =30;
%  M0=100;
%  STD0=150;
%  [thinim, mask] = imgenhance(im, blksze, M0, STD0);
% subplot(1,2,2); subimage((thinim));
% title('Improved thinned input image', 'FontSize', 12); 
% INPUT_IMG=thinim;
% 
% %minutiae extraction 
% thinned= INPUT_IMG;
% img = INPUT_IMG;
% [minutiae, minutiae_img, combined] = findminutiae(thinned, img);
% totminu_I = size(minutiae,1)
% figure,
% subplot(1,2,1), subimage(combined), title('minutiae before postprocess.')
% %______________________________________________________________
% %TO FIND BOUNDARY OF INPUT IMAGE AS WELL AS REGION OF FALSE MINU
% mask_input=mask;
% border=uint8(zeros(m,n));
%   
%  [m,n]=size(mask);
%        validr=uint8(zeros(m,n));
%     thin_temp=thinned;   
%        for i=1:m
%            for j=2:n-1
%                if((mask_input(i,j-1)==0)&&(mask_input(i,j)==1)&&(j<=n-no))
%                      border(i,j)=1;
%                    validr(i,j-nox:j+no)=1; 
%                     thin_temp(i,j-nox:j+no)=1; 
%                end
%                
%                if ((mask_input(i,j+1)==0)&&(mask_input(i,j)==1)&&(j>no))
%                      border(i,j)=1;
%                    validr(i,j+nox:-1:j-no)=1; 
%                    thin_temp(i,j+nox:-1:j-no)=1; 
%                end
%                
%            end
%        end
% 
%         for i=1:m
%            for j=1:n-1:n
%              if (mask_input(i,j)==1)
%                  if (j==1)
%                        border(i,j)=1;
%                    validr(i,j:j+no)=1;
%                    thin_temp(i,j:j+no)=1;
%                  end
%                  if (j==n)
%                        border(i,j)=1;
%                 validr(i,j:-1:j-no)=1;
%                  thin_temp(i,j:-1:j-no)=1;
%                  end
%              end
%            end
%         end
%       
%         
%        
%  for j=1:n
%            for i=2:m-1
%                if((mask_input(i-1,j)==0)&&(mask_input(i,j)==1)&&(i<=m-no))
%                      border(i,j)=1;
%                    validr(i-noy:i+no,j)=1;
%                     thin_temp(i-noy:i+no,j)=1;
%                end
%                if((mask_input(i+1,j)==0)&&(mask_input(i,j)==1)&&(i>no))
%                      border(i,j)=1;
%                     validr(i+noy:-1:i-no,j)=1;
%                      thin_temp(i+noy:-1:i-no,j)=1;
%                end
%                
%            end
%  end
%  
%  for j=1:n
%            for i=1:m-1:m
%              if (mask_input(i,j)==1)
%                if (i==1)
%                      border(i,j)=1;
%                    validr(i:i+no,j)=1;
%                    thin_temp(i:i+no,j)=1;
%                else validr(i:-1:i-no,j)=1;
%                    thin_temp(i:-1:i-no,j)=1;
%                end
%              end
%            end
%  end
% 
%  %___________________________________________________________________
%  % removing minu at the border of roi
% for x=1:size(thinned,1)
%   for y=1:size(thinned,2)
%         if ((validr(x,y)==1)&&(thinned(x,y)==1))
%             combined(x,y,:)=[255,255,255];
%             minutiae_img(x,y,:)=[0,0,0];
%             
%         end
%   end
% end
%     
% for i=1:totminu_I
%     x=minutiae(i,1);
%     y=minutiae(i,2);
%     if ((validr(x,y)==1)&&(thinned(x,y)==1))
%         minutiae(i,:)=0;
%     end
% end
% %__________________________
% 
% subplot(1,2,2), subimage(combined), title('after boundary effect ')
% minu_count=1;
% minutiae_valid(minu_count, :) = [0,0,0,0];  %to make x, y, CN, theta value of minutiae not in border region.
% for i=1:totminu_I
%     CN=minutiae(i,3);
%     if (CN~=0)
%          minutiae_valid(minu_count, :) = minutiae(i,:);
%            minu_count = minu_count + 1;
%     end
% end

% totminu_I= minu_count-1;


k=size(minutiae_valid);
totminu_I=k(1,1);
%FALSE RIDGE BIFURCATION
for i=1:totminu_I
if minutiae_valid(i,3)==3
           wind=ones(m,n);
         xi= minutiae_valid(i,1);
         yi=minutiae_valid(i,2);
         x=xi;
         y=yi;
         wind(xi-wl:xi+wl,yi-wl:yi+wl)=0; %window of size 25 cross 25
         wind(xi,yi)=-1;

      %mark '1', '2', '3'. 
       value=0;

         r=x-1;
         for c=y-1:y+1
             if (thinned(r,c)==1)&&(wind(r,c)==0)
                 value=value+1;
                 wind(r,c)=value;
             end
         end

         c=y+1;
         for r=x-1:x+1
             if (thinned(r,c)==1)&&(wind(r,c)==0)
                 value=value+1;
                 wind(r,c)=value;
             end
         end

         r=x+1;
         for c=y+1:-1:y-1
             if (thinned(r,c)==1)&&(wind(r,c)==0)
                 value=value+1;
                wind(r,c)=value;
             end
         end

         c=y-1;
         for r=x+1:-1:x-1
             if (thinned(r,c)==1)&&(wind(r,c)==0)
                 value=value+1;
                wind(r,c)=value;
             end
         end


for value=1:3  %search '1'/'2/'3' value pixel arond the minutia point in the window.
 for p=x-1:x+1
    for q=y-1:y+1
        if wind(p,q)==value
            xi=p;
            yi=q;
         end
    end
 end

cnt=0;
         while(xi>x-wl)&&(xi<x+wl)&&(yi>y-wl)&&(yi<y+wl) %mark '1'/'2'/'3' to the adjacent connected pixels
             k=0;
             for p=xi-1:xi+1
                 for q=yi-1:yi+1
                     if (thinned(p,q)==1)&&(wind(p,q)==0)
                         wind(p,q)=value;
                          k=k+1;
                         if k==1
                           x1=p;
                           y1=q;
                         end
                         if k==2  %more than one connected pixel
                             cnt=cnt+1;
                             x2=p;
                             y2=q;

                             t1=x1;
                             x1=x2;
                             x2=t1;

                             t2=y1;
                             y1=y2;
                             y2=t2;
                            %___________ 
                             xi=x2;
                             yi=y2;

                         while(xi>x-wl)&&(xi<x+wl)&&(yi>y-wl)&&(yi<y+wl)
                                  k=0;
                                  flag_see=0;
                          for p=xi-1:xi+1

                              for q=yi-1:yi+1

                                   if (thinned(p,q)==1)&&(wind(p,q)==0)
                                            wind(p,q)=value;
                                            flag_see=1;
                                             x3=p;
                                             y3=q;
                                            k=k+1;               
                                   end
                              end
                          end
                          if(flag_see==1)
                          xi=x3;
                          yi=y3;
                          else
                              xi=p;
                              yi=q;

                          end

                              if k==0
                                break
                              end
                          end
%            xi=x1;
%            yi=y1;

                         end
                     end
                 end
             end
             xi=x1;
             yi=y1;
             if k==0
                 break
             end
         end

end  

% figure,subimage(wind);
%to count 0-1, 0-2, 0-3 transition around the boundary clkwise
T=1;
for v=1:3
         T0v=0;
         r=x-wl;
         for c=y-wl:y+(wl-1)
             if (wind(r,c)==0)&&(wind(r,c+1)==v)
                 T0v=T0v+1;
             end
         end

         c=y+wl;
         for r=x-wl:x+(wl-1)
             if (wind(r,c)==0)&&(wind(r+1,c)==v)
                 T0v=T0v+1;
             end
         end

         r=x+wl;
         for c=y+wl:-1:y-(wl-1)
             if (wind(r,c)==0)&&(wind(r,c-1)==v)
                 T0v=T0v+1;
             end
         end

         c=y-wl;
         for r=x+wl:-1:x-(wl-1)
             if (wind(r,c)==0)&&(wind(r-1,c)==v)
                 T0v=T0v+1;
             end
         end

T1=T0v==1;
    T=T & T1;
end
         if T~=1
             minutiae_valid(i,:)=[0 0 0 0];
             combined(x,y,:)=[255,255,255];
         end

end
end


minu_count=1;
minutiae_valid_final(minu_count, :) = [0,0,0,0];  %to make x, y, CN, theta value of minutiae not in border region.
for i=1:totminu_I
    CN = minutiae_valid(i,3);
    if (CN~=0)
         minutiae_valid_final(minu_count, :) = minutiae_valid(i,:);
           minu_count = minu_count + 1;
    end
end

% totminu_I= minu_count-1;
minutiae_valid = minutiae_valid_final;

% figure, subimage(combined);
```

Comment: You can't just dump your entire code here and expect us to fix it.  Please create the smallest possible test-case that you can, and then post that instead.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i was not able to get what the problem is so just dumped the code.. can u please have a look

Comment: No.  Stack Overflow is not a place to get people to do your debugging for you.  Please do some debugging yourself first, so that you can isolate a simple 10-line piece of code that causes the problem.

Comment: looks like a boundary problem

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thnk you oli i am new to this that why i was asking your help, i am totally zero in this field currently . need this code to rum badly this week. But never then less thanks you very much

Comment: @Rasman yes rasman ,, it like to be.. but do you how can i solve this

Comment: @KunalVashist: You need to use the [debugger](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f10-60570.html) to step through your program and find out why it tries to access the array beyond its bounds.  You then need to work backwards to find the bug.

Comment: @KunalVashist: Also, if you have written the code yourself, it may be advisable to add more comments to the code.

Comment: @Jonas sure ,, r u able to figure the problem

Comment: @KunalVashist: No. I don't know what kind of input you give to the function, I have no idea what the function is supposed to do (no comments, not even any help), the variables are only single letters, which makes everything even harder to follow. If you want help with this, you have to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

At lines 212 and 213 you create nested loops that loop over nine elements of wind looking for elements that match some sort of condition.  When you find one, you change the center of your nine element block.

The problem arises when the center of your block is on an edge of wind.  When you look over the nine elements centered at an edge you must not access indices in the same way, otherwise you get the error as in above.  To illustrate a simple case of this:

```
a = rand(4,4);
for p=2:4
   for q = 1:3
     tmp += a(p,q)
   end
end
```

sums the 9 elements of a (a square array) centered at (3,2).

```
a = rand(4,4);
for p=3:5
   for q = 1:3
     tmp += a(p,q)
   end
end
```

will generate the same error that you have when it tries to access a(5,1) because this element of the array does not exist.  The correct way to fix this depends on what you're trying to do, but that's most definitely beyond the scope of your question, and our ability to figure out.

I hope this helps.

Echoing some of the comments, I'd like to offer you a piece of advice.  In the future, you're much more likely to get on taget, quality answers if you can boil your question down to the shortest possible test case.  This is also a valuable step in debugging your own code.  Figuring out how to construct a test case will often make the answer to your problem apparent.  When it's not apparent, Stackoverflow is an excellent resource.